# Communicate from Datadog Dashboard to an application running in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, datadog

I need to develop a Datadog dashboard which will monitor metrics, logs of the applications running in AWS EC2. At the same time i have some need to send some messages to Application from Datadog Dashboard. Is it possible to do that? If it is not what are the alternative i can use to achieve this.

Comment: What sort of messages?

Comment: Something like changing the log level. Turn On Debug Logs or can be some custom log level handled in the application. The application can provide a RestEndpoint to listen to the requests sent by Datadog.